# Ramda array to multiple argument function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Given the input of string `6-10`, I want to obtain a list of numbers `[6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10]`.

This is what I have come up with:

```
const x = "6-10";
const sizeMinMax = R.pipe(R.split('-'), R.map(parseInt))
sizeMinMax(x); //[6,10]

const sizesStepped = (min, max) => R.unfold(minSize => minSize > max ? false : [minSize, minSize + 0.5], min)
sizesStepped(8,10); // [8,8.5,9,9.5,10]
```

How do I pipe the output of `sizeMinMax(x)` which is an array to `sizeStepped` function with 2 arguments?

Comment: Try `sizesStepped.apply(null, sizeMinMax(x));`

Comment: `var sizesStepped = (min, max) => Array.from({length: (max - min) * 2 + 1}, (_, i) => min + i*0.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `sizesStepped` with R.apply:

```js
const sizeMinMax = R.pipe(R.split('-'), R.map(parseInt))

const sizesStepped = (min, max) => R.unfold(minSize => minSize > max ? false : [minSize, minSize + 0.5], min)

const fn = R.pipe(sizeMinMax, R.apply(sizesStepped));

const x = "6-10"

const result = fn(x)

console.log(result); // [8,8.5,9,9.5,10]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in vanilla JavaScript by implementing a range method.

```js
const range = (start, stop, step) =>
  Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1 }, (_, i) => start + i * step);

const x = '6-10';
const [s, e] = x.split('-');
const step = 0.5;
const ret = range(+s, +e, step);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: While I appreciate the solution to my problem with vanilla javascript, I was looking more for a [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) solution, I apologise for not stating this.